# How to get Message Delivery Receipts when receiver app is in killed mode using XMPP iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework, remote-notifications

I need help to reach out to this problem in XMPP.

**Scenario**

There are two users (**User A & User B**).

1. **A** is online and **B** Killed his application.
2. **A** send a message to **B** and **A** need a message delivery receipt from **B** but **B** is not connected with **XMPP**.
3. So **B** is not connected with XMPP which means **A** will not get a delivery receipt until **B** not connected with **XMPP**.
4. For solving out above problem we implement **Remote Notification** when the user is **Offline**.
5. Now **A** send message to **B** and **B** received **Remote Notification**.
6. **B** WakeUp his App and Make a connection with **XMPP** and Now **A** received a delivery receipt.

Using 5 & 6 points, I can solve the above problem, but this makes one new issue(You can suggest the best way to do the above).

When **B** makes a connection with **XMPP**. his last seen showing as **ONLINE**.

I need when **B** connect from Killed Mode I don't want to show as **ONLINE**.

Thank You in advance for your solution.

Comment: Is that a question posed by your employer or something?

Comment: No it is posted by me and I am working on above functionality. @ElTomato